# Normal Distribution Probability Comparisons

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

I am working on a Normal Distribution problem and am a bit stuck. As the image shows below these are the probabilities associated with values corresponding to their distance from the mean (one standard deviation, two standard deviations, etc.).

[image]

Say that we are given (for simplicity) that the mean $\mu$ = 0 as is shown in the picture and that the standard deviation $\sigma$ = 1.

We are then asked which value is larger:

The probability that X falls between $-{1\over2}$ and ${1\over2}$ or two other options:

1. X falls in between 1 and 2
2. X is greater than 1

What I have done to solve this is the following:

We know for sure that the probability that X falls between 1 and 2 to be .14 percent. For X greater than 1 we know it to be .16 percent. We therefore need to compare these values to X between $-{1\over2}$ and ${1\over2}$. However, this is where I am stuck. We know that since more density falls closer towards the middle (mean) that the probability in-between $-{1\over2}$ and ${1\over2}$ is larger than .17 + .17 = .34. Can we conclude then from this that the probability in between $-{1\over2}$ and ${1\over2}$ is larger than both of the other two? Even though we cannot arrive at this value explicitly?

Comment: I agree with your reasoning.